# DLL crashes C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll

My colleague and myself wrote a DLL which we're now trying to use in another application. When we use functions from that DLL in our application when using a web cam the app crashes. When we copy and paste the exact same code the application works.
If we are using a image instead of a web cam then it also works with DLL.
We made a new app just to test it and when using that DLL is still doesn't work.

We're really confused because we get different exceptions and we really don't know what's wrong. Are there any general errors that could cause this? Is there a way we could debug this?

Code is as follows:

```
    private glyphRecognizer recognize = new glyphRecognizer();
    picturebox1.image = recognize.recognitionStep1_Grayscaling((Bitmap)picturebox1.image);
```

And for DLL:

```
    public Bitmap recognitionStep1_Grayscaling(Bitmap image)
    {
        BitmapData data = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, image.PixelFormat);
        UnmanagedImage originalImage = new UnmanagedImage(data);
        image.UnlockBits(data);

        //grayscaling
        UnmanagedImage grayImage = null;
        if (data.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)
        {
            grayImage = originalImage;
        }
        else
        {
            grayImage = UnmanagedImage.Create(originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
            Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.BT709.Apply(originalImage, grayImage);
        }
        return grayImage.ToManagedImage();
    }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @MichaC it's the Unhandled exception in Bitmap.Drawing is the one the comes up the most...
Now it gives us System.NullReference exception.

Comment: Could it be you're passing a reference to an object that has an unmanaged part which is sometimes disposed of before the dll uses it? How about copy the bitmap to a new object before passing it to the dll?

Comment: @user1318499 We've tried that but the error was the same. Regarding that, we've tried putting the picture in a new picturebox and using that picturebox... Is that what you meant or should I try it again using something else?

Comment: Surely, you stepped through the code step-by-step and checked that there is no null object. What line is the exception thrown at?

Comment: @NicoSchertler The exception is thrown every time we try to call something from the DLL or inside a .cs file where I try to make a new form!

Comment: Have you tried stepping into the unmanaged dll?  Compile your linked dll in Debug mode and enable stepping into the code from the managed application:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdw0c6sf(v=vs.90).aspx